# jQuery - add different ids to next sibling

Tags: jquery

The following code adds the same ID to every div sibling:

```
var d = 0;
var newid = currentId.substring(currentId.length-8, currentId.length-1)+d;

$.each(('table').next(), function() {
    $('table').find('div[id|="edid"]').attr("id", newid);   
    d++;
});
```

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<table><tr><td><div id="edid-0-">text</div></td></tr></table>
<br>
<table><tr><td><div id="edid-0-">text</div></td></tr></table>
<br>
<table><tr><td><div id="edid-0-">text</div></td></tr></table>
```

After running my code, the IDs should look like: `edid-0-0`, `edid-0-1`, `edid-0-2`, and so on.

But instead, all are either `edid-0-0`, `edid-0-0`, `did-0-0`...
                         or `edid-0-3`, `edid-0-3`, `edid-0-3`...

depending on where i put the variables (in or outside the each function).

I tried various variations, but it's always the same ID ending, und no continuing numberation. I kind of understand why this happens, but I have no clue on how solving this problem. Sitting here for hours. My head -> explodes.

Comment: aply newid always before adding in each function

Comment: Why are you doing this on the client side?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since d is always 0, why dont you just use the index parameter in the `function()`

Also, you are doing `$("table")` during each iteration, which will query the dom again.  I assume you actually want `$(this)` which will find the `<div/>` under the current `<table/>`

```
var newid = currentId.substring(currentId.length-8, currentId.length-1)+d;
$.each($('table').next(), function(index, elm) {
    $(this).find('div[id|="edid"]').attr("id", newid + index);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value "newid" (which never changes), but you are incrementing "d".

Answer (score 0):

SImple: move

```
var newid = currentId.substring(currentId.length-8, currentId.length-1)+d;
```

inside `S.each` callback function to redefine the ID string on every iteration. Also, is it really adding the ID to the next table? To me it seems that code was supposed to add the IDs to the '
's.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this :

```
var newid = currentId.substring(currentId.length-8, currentId.length-1)+d;
```

in your each